# Window 10 versions "final" end of life (EOL) (no more security updates)

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

I know the official Windows 10 (Pro) EOL table [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/products/windows-10-home-and-pro). However, (most) versions will still get security updates past those dates. E.g. Windows 10 1909 still got updates with the May 2021 Patch Tuesday although the official "end date" was Nov 12, 2019.

Is there an official EOL date that includes the discontinuing of the security updates? Going by the [Enterprise and Education list](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/products/windows-10-enterprise-and-education) seems like a safe bet (the EOL for 1803 there is the same date the Pro version received their last security updates) since e.g. [according to this source](https://www.zdnet.com/article/windows-10-these-versions-just-reached-end-of-service-no-more-security-patches-coming/) ] 1803, 1809 and 1909 got the update in May 2021, or did I misunderstood the article and the security update only applied to the Enterprise and Education versions (as the [MS Lifecycle FAQ](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/faq/windows) says)?

I'm sort of confused if the EOL actually means there are no more security updates (different sources seem to point to different answers), I would appreciate any insights!

PS. Wikipedia has a good/better overview of [all Win EOLs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_10_version_history#Channels)

Comment: In my personal experience unsupported versions of Windows cannot download cumulative updates. The cumulative updates for those versions are being released for editions where that version is supported.

Comment: apparently the "correct" answer is that after the EOL there will be a "forced" feature update [see here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/announcements/windows-10-1803-end-of-servicing). Now that I think of, I think I remember that triggering the manual update of a Win10 Version that was EOL started the update to the new version as well.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are no security updates for Windows 10 versions past their EOL (I was wrong with my initial premise in the question). Once EOL is reached an update to a new feature version is forced.

Comment: If you downvote, which is perfectly acceptable, please be a team player, and please consider leaving a suggestion on how to improve the answer. Thank you.